# Why do we have pronunciation for the word “liquorice” as ‘liquorish’?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Is there any difference in pronunciation between the American and British speakers?

Comment: Just an FYI that people normal use the phrase '[Native Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States)' to mean "the indigenous population of America" rather than English language "native speakers" in America.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My go-to source on the idiosyncrasies of English spelling has the following entry:

> > [image: Page 947]
>
> [*English Pronunciation 1500 - 1700* by E J Dobson](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9582.1959.tb00399.x)

As the quoted entry says, the version with /ʃ/ arose as a dialectal pronunciation and then spread in other dialects. Dobson says that Cooper preferred the spelling *licorish* to ***liquorish*** which alludes to the fact that the latter was an alternative spelling of *liquorice*.  (Cooper's *Grammatica Linguae Anglicanae* was published in 1685.)

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liquorish%2Cliquorice&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cliquorish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliquorice%3B%2Cc0), there are many instances of *liquorish* from 1585 onwards.

In Modern English, 'liquorice' has two possible pronunciations:

- /ˈlɪk(ə)rɪs/
- /ˈlɪk(ə)rɪʃ/

The second one is by far the most common and widespread pronunciation of *liquorice*. There's also a difference in spelling:

- *liquorice* is mainly used in the UK and some other varieties of English
- *licorice* is mostly used in the US

Both pronunciations are common in the UK and the US. As per [this blog post by J C Wells](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/blog0712a.htm):

> The oldest American dictionaries I have to hand are the big Random House (1967) and Kenyon & Knott’s Pronouncing Dictionary of American English (1953). Both include /-ʃ/ while prioritizing /-s/. **More recent American dictionaries generally prioritize /-ʃ/**. *It may well be the case that /-ʃ/ gradually spread in the States before spreading here in Britain*.
>
> [Emphasis mine]

There's a comprehensive entry on *liquorice* in [*More Word Histories And Mysteries* From Aardvark to Zombie Houghton Mifflin Harcourt (2006) (American Heritage Dictionary)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UbXao0TjfKgC&q=liquorice#v=snippet&q=liquorice&f=false), it says that the (original) Middle English pronunciation of *liquorice* seems to have been the version with /s/. It goes on to say that:

> The first indications of the new pronunciation [with /ʃ/], through spellings like *likerish*, begin to occur in the 18th century. The great American lexicographer Noah Webster, for instance, criticized the spelling of the word *licorice* as *lickerish* in his influential and popular spelling guide published in 1783. Webster himself advocated the spelling *liquorice* in this work, rather than *licorice*. (In this regard, it is interesting to note the existence of a now almost obsolete adjective *lickerish* meaning “delicious” when applied to food and “fond of good food” when applied to persons. Although this fact suggests the tantalizing possibility that the adjective *lickerish* influenced the pronunciation of *licorice*, the ultimate origins of the pronunciation with (sh) have yet to be determined.) Throughout the 19th and 20th centuries, commentators on linguistic usage disparaged the pronunciation with (sh) as lower-class or uneducated, but it nevertheless remains widespread in the United States today—despite the usual spelling of the word with the letters *—ce*, which most often indicates the sound (s) at the end of English words [as in *face, ice, nice* etc].

Comment: For what it's worth, since 1893, the spelling "licorice" has been more common than "liquorice"

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In the US, and also Canada I think.  I believe "liquorice" is still more common in the UK and other English-speaking places.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I've never in my entire life seen *licorice* until today.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Just using the default English corpus from [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licorice%2C+liquorice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicorice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliquorice%3B%2Cc0), so I don't know about AmE/BrE bias.

Comment: pronouncing liquorice with an /s/ sounds really weird to my British ears (Modern RP-speaker from SE England, late 20s) so I'd say the /ʃ/ pronunciation has either won out, or pretty close to it

Comment: @JeffZeitlin looking at the British corpus liquorice is still preferred here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licorice%2Cliquorice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3 with the US switching in the 1870s https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licorice%2Cliquorice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3

Comment: Perhaps it might be helpful to add to the answer the fact that not only is there a difference of pronunciation between BrE and AmE, there is also a difference of spelling.

Comment: @shoover: updated

Comment: Whatever part of the text in your image is relevant, please could you include this in your answer in plain text?

Comment: @RosieF: Yep. I'll do it when I have time